# Why do chains in Bridge type tables have different (default) priority values in nftables?

Tags: firewall, nftables

As the man page clearly shows https://www.netfilter.org/projects/nftables/manpage.html , the default "filter" priority value for Bridge table chains -200, while it is 0 for all table types, but why is that? I have found no resources explaining the reasoning behind this decision.

[image: packet flow diagram]

Going by the (old) packet flow diagram, the priority value shouldn't influence the processing priorities for chains of **different** hooks (it doesn't). So what is the purpose of the different priority values?

My current conjecture is that it's merely indicative of the general stage in the traversal process. So in ip/ipv6/inet table chains, -300 represents the point where connection tracking kicks in (https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Netfilter_hooks), so a value of -200 in bridge table chains would represent a point beyond that, although technically speaking, because the hooks' processing order is not influenced by priority values, the values could as well be -600 or 300 and it wouldn't actually change the processing order of "inter-hook" chains.

Comment: I'm not answering the question. But today (since kernel 5.3), there might be an interaction with conntrack in bridge path (kernel module nf_conntrack_bridge , *not* the older deprecated kernel module br_netfilter  (represented by the green boxes in the blue field of your picture) that should be avoided with nftables) which itself hooks at priority -200 . So if you're using an nftables stateful firewalling bridge, you might want to do tests to know if `ct state new` matches the same in the forward hook at priority -210, -200 or -190 ...

Comment: Interesting, I can't test it myself right now because raspbian doesn't seem to have the modules (and I think it was you who pointed that in another post, thank you for that!)